# Spring MVC handler mapping not working

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am very new to Spring MVC and have been following tutorials but they don't seem to be working.

I can load my index.jsp file fine but when I try to map it to the Dispatcher Servlet I keep getting resource not found errors.

HelloWorldController:

```
package com.javatpoint;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;  

@Controller  
public class HelloWorldController {  

    @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {  

        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC";  
        return new ModelAndView("hellopage", "message", message);  
    }  

}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app version="2.5"   
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">  
 <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  
    <context:component-scan  base-package="com.javatpoint" />  
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

my jsp files hellopage.jsp and welcomepage.jsp are in the folder jsp under my WEB-INF folder.
Index.jsp:

```
<a href="hello.html">click</a>|  
<a href="welcome.html">click</a>
```

I am trying to map hello.html to the HelloWorldController.java.

I would greatly appreciate any help as I am having problems mapping the first Spring MVC application.

Comment: What URLs have you tried? Looks like you should try localhost:8080/<projectname>/hello.html and add .html in your requestmapping

Comment: http://localhost:8080/QuickTapMVC/hello.html
http://localhost:8080/QuickTapMVC/index.jsp

The goal was for the link in index.jsp (hello.html) to launch the controller and return the hellopage.jsp message

Comment: did you try `@RequestMapping("/hello.html")`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your servlet mapping, try changing it in your web.xml to:

`<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

your url-pattern is set to *.html. Therefore only requests that ends with ".html" will be dispatched to spring mvc.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
```

to your servlet-mapping in web.js.

Comment: That did not work. After I made that change I wasn't able to load index.jsp anymore. This is what I put on my web.xml file:
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>  
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

Can you try @RequestMapping(value="/hello",method = RequestMethod.GET ) ?

Comment: Tried that and still doesn't map to it

Comment: Can you send the displayed log at the begining of deployment ?

Answer (score 0):

Your url pattern in the `servlet-mapping` is wrong.

You're saying go to the dispatcher servlet when the URL matches this:

*.html

So when you use "hello.html" the DispatcherServlet gets triggered.

However, there is no mapping for `hello.html`. There's only one for `hello`. HTML is static content, and it's not typical to serve that through a controller.

Try this:

Change the url-pattern to this:

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

Change the `hello.html` to `hello.jsp`

Change your method signature to return a string, and add the `Model` to the method.

```
 @RequestMapping("/hello")  
 public String helloWorld(Model model) {  
   return "hello";
 }
```

Your anchor tags should then point to the correct mapping. They'll look like this:

```
<a href="hello">click</a>|
```

So how does this work? These two pieces:

```
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

-

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
</bean>
```

The above is a pretty standard. In the servlet mapping, it's saying that anything that matches that URL pattern should hit the servlet named `spring` you defined in the web.xml.

The view resolver is looking in the `/WEB-INF/jsp/` directory for files ending in `.jsp`. In other words, Spring will look for `/WEB-INF/jsp/<string>.jsp`. So when you return a String `hello` in the method, it is actually going to attempt to resolve `/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp`.

If you understand the above, you may have realized you can serve `*.html` files this way also. They would require their own view resolver, however.

Comment: I followed you steps and made the change so the link now points to hello.jsp. However I still get the same error message: Resource not found.
/QuickTapMVC/hello.jsp

Comment: You don't understand. The mapping is not to `hello.jsp` or `hello.html`. The mapping points to `/hello`. The mapping must point to the exact value of `@RequestMapping`. If you want it to do `hello.jsp`, it should say `@RequestMapping("hello.jsp")`

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I changed the a href link to point to hello instead of hello.html(or hello.jsp), I changed my servlet mapping section in my web.xml file to what you mentioned above, spring followed by the '/' character. In addition, I copied and pasted your bean definition to make sure I didn't make a typo.

When I click the link button, the URL looks like this:
http://localhost:8080/QuickTapMVC/hello
I still get a tomcat 404 error stating the resource is not available.

How does the servlet xml know which controller class to use ?

Comment: I am starting to think maybe something is wrong with my tomcat configuration

Comment: I wasn't explicit, but the hello.jsp should be in `/WEB-INF/jsp/` since that is where the view resolver is looking. Other than that, pay attention to the console logs when the server is starting. There will be log entries telling you what gets mapped. And a 404 doesn't mean the controller isn't getting hit, by the way. Console log entries will be more specific.